# Give A same value as B without making them interconnected

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm working with dates and my code is like the following:

(currentDate is just the actual date to remember and shownDate is a variable that is changed in a function to get date specific data from my database

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var shownDate = currentDate;
```

Now if I change shownDate (like add 7 days) currentDate is changed as well. I know that assigning variables like that makes shownDate something like pointing at currentDate thus changing it as well.

Let me know if you need some more code or anything else.

Comment: Just create a new Date from `currentDate` and set `shownDate` to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone with `new Date`:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var shownDate = new Date(currentDate);
```

Comment: Thanks fore the quick help, I'll accept the answer as soon I'm able to :)